# DirectAdmin (web control cpanel) : Node JS Express App - App Route return 404 not found

Tags: node.js, api, cpanel, shared-hosting, directadmin

I have setup my Nodejs app on Cpanel **Setup Node.js App** plugin on my DirectAdmin web panel.

```
var http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const UserRoutes = require('./routes/user');
var server = http.createServer(app);
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
app.use(cors());
// Static file folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/user', UserRoutes);
module.export = app;
server.listen();
```

My index file is running and not showing any error, but once I hit the API route it returns me `Cannot GET /api/`

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any handler/middleware for `/api` routing.
You should define:

`app.use('/api', apiRoutes)`

where apiRoutes is gonna be a middleware which routes to the right controllers.

There's no handler for this route, so express engine returns 404.

Comment: app.use('/user', UserRoutes); I am calling my middleware in the above code. Please review it properly.

Comment: You are routing /user and not /api.

Comment: I need routing as /user not /api

Comment: what's the request's path you execute?

Comment: Your'e probably executing a request which starts with /api

Comment: Just execute something that starts with /users and there's a handler on UsersRoutes that accepts this path.